# After disabling Vertex Attribute Array how glDrawArrays() works?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have started learning Opengl ES 2.0 for android. I am working with code segment taken from the following site:
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-two-ambient-and-diffuse-lighting/
Here is a light point with 4 numbers:

```
    private final float[] mLightPosInModelSpace = new float[] {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

This lightpoint is in model space. The following function is used to draw the point with disabled Vertex Attribute Array.

```
private void drawLight()
{
    final int pointMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPointProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    final int pointPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mPointProgramHandle, "a_Position");

    // Pass in the position.
    GLES20.glVertexAttrib3f(pointPositionHandle, mLightPosInModelSpace[0], mLightPosInModelSpace[1], mLightPosInModelSpace[2]);

    // Since we are not using a buffer object, disable vertex arrays for this attribute.
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(pointPositionHandle);  

    // Pass in the transformation matrix.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mLightModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(pointMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);


    // Draw the point.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}
```

I read the documentation from here: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml
and see that after enabling vertex Attribute Array `glDrawArrays()` get points from that enabled array. But my question is from where `glDrawArrays()` get the points? In this example and it works fine taking the point from `mLightPosInModelSpace` . Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK glVertexAttrib3f passes the one value drawing one point needs.

Comment: Then it would be ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Section 2.7 of the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec, "**Current Vertex State**":

> Current generic attribute values define generic attributes for a vertex when a
>   vertex array defining that data is not enabled, as described in section 2.8.
>
> A current
>   value may be changed at any time by issuing one of the commands
>
> - `void VertexAttrib{1234}{f}( uint index, T values );`
> - `void VertexAttrib{1234}{f}v( uint index, T values );`
>
> to load the given value(s) into the current generic attribute for slot index, whose
>   components are named x, y, z, and w.

Then on pg 21, the spec explains how they're pulled:

> If
>   an array corresponding to a generic attribute required by a vertex shader is not enabled,
>   then the corresponding element is taken from the current generic attribute
>   state (see section 2.7).